# Why make a new Promise?

Tags: angular, function, asynchronous, memory-management, service

The [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) I follow has this function (where `Hero` is a class and `HEROES` an array):

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }
}
```

Now it wants to simulate a slow connection and defines this:

```
getHeroesSlowly(): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // Simulate server latency with 2 second delay
    setTimeout(() => resolve(this.getHeroes()), 2000);
  });
}
```

where it uses `new`, without explaining why it creates a new `Promise` now, while it didn't do so before. Any idea?

Comment: Instead of deleting my comment, begging for advice in improving my question, please tell me what I should do to make my question better *or* what's already wrong with it.

Comment: Your question is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are simply using the Promise constructor to define the specific `resolve()` function. Here is what it looks like in JS :

```
return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(function () { return resolve(_this.nextQuote()); }, 500);
});
```

---

You can also see that in the ES6 library, where the PromiseConstructor is defined :

```
interface PromiseConstructor {
    /**
     * A reference to the prototype.
     */
    readonly prototype: Promise<any>;

    /**
     * Creates a new Promise.
     * @param executor A callback used to initialize the promise. This callback is passed two arguments:
     * a resolve callback used resolve the promise with a value or the result of another promise,
     * and a reject callback used to reject the promise with a provided reason or error.
     */
    new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): Promise<T>;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Obviously, the example in JS is about another example where they call a `_this.nextQuote()` method.

Answer (score 1):

It returns a new Promise so as to simulate a `HttpServer` call which will be a new call every time you invoke the method . which is generally time taking.

If we donot use a new promise the previous promise will be resolved and the value returned instantly.

Comment: But the timeout would last 2 seconds, even though we have the data hot and ready to be served, right? Also, if you are the downvoter, please mention what's wrong with the question, so that I can improve it.

Comment: @gsamaras i didnt dv or i woudnt have answered, the promise will resolve immediately if we didnt put the timeout for the first call and for the rest we are using new promise. which will replicate the scenario instead of resolving the previous promise

Comment: So you mean that it will wait 2 seconds to call `this.getHeroes()` and *then* create a `new Promise`, which will sumilate the `HttpServer` call? Oh I see an upvote in mu question, in case it is you, tnx!

Comment: yes this is what i feel it does ? dont eat me if i am wrong on this but i am quite sure

Answer (score 1):

HEROES is already defined. The data is available so it can be returned immediately as you can see: `Promise.resolve(HEROES);`.

The new Promise is used to resolve the data at a later stage. (after 2 seconds in your example).

Comment: But the timeout would last 2 seconds, even though we have the data hot and ready to be served, right? Also, if you are the downvoter, please mention what's wrong with the question, so that I can improve it.

Comment: The timeout is there for example purposes.

Comment: Yes it is, but that timeout is what will make the Promise stall for 2 seconds, I guess, isn't it?

Comment: Using setTimeout you basically say: do something after X amount of miliseconds